# Is there a bittorrent like http download manager?

Tags: kubuntu, bittorrent

Just wondering if there is a bit torrent like http/ftp download manager.

When downloading a big file with Bit torrent it creates the full dummy file initially and downloads multiple 2MB pieces simultaneously and fills the file. Even when interrupted many times it never corrupts the data. And we can use the partially downloaded files from one PC and complete the download in second PC. So , can I download http files with such features.

Comment: One thing to mention that HTTP protocol does not strictly require the server to specify the size of the download or to be able to resume the download from an arbitrary point, which is crucial for such application to work. So the support for this would depend also on the web server which serves the file.

Comment: HTTP also has no hashing algorithm to verify whether any parts of the data were corrupted or if the file changed between separate requests, etc.  That said, there are HTTP download managers which attempt to solve these issues by overlapping the start of the new segment with the end of the last successfully downloaded segment and so on.  (I'd answer the question, but I haven't actually used any on Linux).

Comment: @Sergey Many web servers currently support resume capability and apps like wget always request to resume from arbitrary point . I'm asking about resumable files only. Few download managers have multi segment downloads with all segments being able to resume when interrupted. How different is this from bit torrent?

Comment: @neon_overload Agreed that the lack of hashing function will make verifying downloads not possible.

Comment: @neon_overload If this question remains open long enough, I recommend posting something like that as an answer. This is really asking if there is a download manager that uses HTTP as though it were BitTorrent, not what download managers are available in general.

Comment: @qbi I believe the two questions are asking completely different things...